# If $A \vDash B$ then $A, C \vDash B$

Tags: logic

If $A \vDash B$ then $A, C \vDash B$

I just wanna check if my thinking is correct. What stands above is untrue because if $A$ true, then $B$ true, independent from $C$.

Therefore, premise $C$ can be false while $B$ is true which conflicts the definition of entailment.

Comment: Your argument is wrong; if $A$ and $C$ are both true, then $A$ will be so, and thus $B$ must be true, according to $A \vDash B$.

Comment: Yeah but I though for $A, C \vDash B$ to be true, it requires that the conclusion is true, only if both premises to be true, doesn't it? But in the example A true and C false yields B true.

Comment: No! $C$ false and $B$ true does **not** contradict that definition - you have something backwards

Comment: $A, C \vDash B$ does *not* mean "$A, C$ *and* $B$" are always true. It means "*if* $A$ and $C$ are both true *then* $B$ is also true". If $A$ and $C$ are not both true, then $B$ can be whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As correctly remarked by Mauro Allegranza in his comment, $A \models B$ means that every time $A$ is true then $B$ is true as well, i.e. it is impossible that $A$ is true and $B$ is false. As a consequence, if $A \models B$ then $A, C \models B$, because every time $A$ *and* $C$ are true, in particular $A$ is true and hence (since we are supposing $A \models B$) $B$ is true.